# How to load windows cursors (.cur) in Linux using XLib and Xcursors?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xlib, glfw

I'm trying to load a `.cur` file via **[Xcursor](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xcursor)** library and i just can't make it work. I'm working with linux *(Bodhi + Lubuntu)* on virtualbox. Here's my code:

**my includes**

```
// GLFW
#define GLFW_DLL       // use the GLFW .dll
#include "gl/GLFW/glfw3.h"

...

#if defined(__linux__)
   // GLFW native expoose
   #define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_X11        // expose X11 and GLX context (linux)
   #define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_GLX
   #include "gl/GLFW/glfw3native.h"      // for low-level expose
   // X Window
   #include <X11/X.h> 
   #include <X11/Xlib.h> 
   #include <X11/Xutil.h>
   #include <X11/Xcursor/Xcursor.h>
#endif
```

**in program, after GLFW window creation**

```
#if defined(__linux__)
   Display* dpy = glfwGetX11Display();
   Window xwindow = glfwGetX11Window(window);
   Cursor crs = XcursorFilenameLoadCursor(dpy,"somefolder/default.cur");
   XDefineCursor(dpy,xwindow,crs);
#endif

...

#if defined(__linux__)
   XFreeCursor(dpy,crs);
#endif
```

Any obvious error? I can't really find sources about `Xcursor` and i'm close to switch to typical OpenGL textures and get over it.

**NOTE:** I'm already disabled Virtualbox integrated mouse, so the mouse is entirely on guest machine and i run it fullscreen.

Comment: You code works here (Archlinux, with xmonad or Xfce/xfwm and a cursor from [there](http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Arch+Cursor+Theme+%28simple%29?content=135902)).

Comment: @Leiaz, thank you for the comment. I assume the cursor you tested with is `.xbm` (x window bitmap) ? From documentation [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xcursorfilenameloadcursor) i can't really find out if _Xcursor_ supports `.cur` or not. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: Oh .. that is probably the problem. `file` says it's a "X11 cursor". `.cur` seems to be a Windows format. The Xcursor file format is defined in the man page, I don't think it's possible to use another format directly. There is a [`xcursorgen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xcursorgen) utility to create a Xcursor from PNG file(s).

Comment: @Leiaz, thank you. I had the impression `.cur` are compatible with Xcursor, but they're not. Even `.xbm` or `.xpm` were not loaded. Your cursors loaded as well :) although i can't find out what they are or how to create them (i mean, specs) The only thing for sure their header start with `Xcur..`. Convert PNGs to `xcursor` i don't find it really good since i want to be able to use the same cursor in Windows/Linux and don't like really to provide hotspots as well; perhaps some internal conversion from `.cur` to xcurso` might be the way once i find out the `xcursor` format. I'll post my results.

Comment: There was a problem in Oracle Virtualbox `not able to show hardware cursors on OpenGL context`; they've shown under it and this is known issue (as i learnt) for quite some time now. This gave the impression of cursors-not-loaded. I just switched to VMware and it doesn't suffering from this.

Comment: They *are* "X11 cursor" : magic bytes : CARD32 'Xcur' (0x58, 0x63, 0x75, 0x72) (a CARD32 is a 32bit unsigned int). As written in the man page : the [documentation you linked](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xcursor), in the section "CURSOR FILES", the file format is described there :) If you don't want to create a file, look in Xcursor.h : `XCursorImageCreate`/`Destroy` `XCursorImageLoadCursor`

Comment: @Leiaz, yes i found it and i'm already on `XCursorImageCreate` approach, it seems the most cross-platform way. Thank you, i'll post my results later for the ones encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since i solved my problem i decided it's a good idea to post my results, in hope of helping someone trying to make his application more cross-platform. 
My code follows, and explanation follows the code.

**ESSENTIAL**

- X11 development headers package (etc. *libx11-dev*)
- Xcursor development headers package (etc. *libxcursor-dev*)
- A portable `<stdint.h>` header, like [this](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/courses/CStudio/SDCC%20Compiler/sdcc-src-2.8.0/sdcc-src-2.8.0/sdcc/support/Util/pstdint.h) one.

**CODE**

```
...
// to store colors
struct COLOR {
   uint8_t r,g,b,a;
   COLOR() {
      this->r = this->g = this->b = this->a = 0;
   }
   COLOR(uint8_t r,uint8_t g,uint8_t b) {
      this->r = r;
      this->g = g;
      this->b = b;
      this->a = 255;
   }
   bool operator == (COLOR c) const {
      return (r == c.r && g == c.g && b == c.b);
   }
};

size_t get_bit(int32_t number,int8_t position) {
   size_t bitmask = 1 << position;
   return (number & bitmask) ? 1 : 0;
}

....
// load cursor
#if defined(_WIN32)
   // etc. use standard WinApi code, (HCURSOR)LoadImage(..) and such
#endif
#if defined(__linux__)

  Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

  string filename = "mycursor.cur";    // <-- add your .cur cursor here
  char buf[4];
  FILE* fp = fopen(filename.c_str(),"rb");
  fread(buf,1,2,fp);    // reserved. always 0
  fread(buf,1,2,fp);    // image type; we're only interested for .cur (=2)
  int16_t imagetype = buf[0] | (buf[1]<<8);
  if (imagetype!=2) {
     // error:  file is not a valid .cur file
     return;
  }
  fread(buf,1,2,fp);    // number of images
  // we're only interested in the first image
  fread(buf,1,1,fp);    // width  (0 to 255; 0=means 256 width)
  int8_t width = (buf[0]==0 ? 256 : buf[0]);
  fread(buf,1,1,fp);    // height (0 to 255; 0=means 256 height)
  int8_t height = (buf[0]==0 ? 256 : buf[0]);
  fread(buf,1,1,fp);    // number of colors in palette (0 for no palette)
  fread(buf,1,1,fp);    // reserved. should be 0
  fread(buf,1,2,fp);    // hotspot x
  int16_t hotspot_x = buf[0] | (buf[1]<<8);
  fread(buf,1,2,fp);    // hotspot y
  int16_t hotspot_y = buf[0] | (buf[1]<<8);
  fread(buf,1,4,fp);    // image data in bytes
  fread(buf,1,4,fp);    // offset to image data

  // Now we need to verify if image in .cur is BMP or PNG (Vista+)
  // We can't just check 'magic' since if it's BMP, the header will be missing (PNG is whole)
  // So we search for PNG magic; if doesnt exist, we have a BMP!
  // NOTE:  for simplicity we go only for BMP for the moment. 
  //        So just check if 'biSize' is 40 (Windows NT & 3.1x or later)

  // BITMAPINFOHEADER 
  fread(buf,1,4,fp);    // biSize
  int32_t biSize = (buf[0]&0xff) | (buf[1]<<8) | (buf[2]<<16) | (buf[3]<<24);
  if (biSize!=40) {
     // error:  file does not contain valid BMP data;
     return;
  }
  fread(buf,1,4,fp);    // biWidth
  int32_t biWidth = (buf[0]&0xff) | (buf[1]<<8) | (buf[2]<<16) | (buf[3]<<24);
  fread(buf,1,4,fp);    // biHeight (if positive => bottom-up, if negative => up-bottom)
  int32_t biHeight = (buf[0]&0xff) | (buf[1]<<8) | (buf[2]<<16) | (buf[3]<<24);
  fread(buf,1,2,fp);    // biPlanes
  fread(buf,1,2,fp);    // biBitCount         
  int16_t biBitCount = (buf[0]&0xff) | (buf[1]<<8) | (buf[2]<<16) | (buf[3]<<24);
  if (biBitCount!=24 && biBitCount!=32) {
     // error:  only 24/32 bits supported;
     return;
  }
  fread(buf,1,4,fp);    // biCompression
  int32_t biCompression = (buf[0]&0xff) | (buf[1]<<8) | (buf[2]<<16) | (buf[3]<<24);
  // we want only uncompressed BMP data
  if (biCompression!=0 /*BI_RGB*/ ) {
     // error:  file is compressed; only uncompressed BMP is supported;
     return;
  }
  fread(buf,1,4,fp);    // biSizeImage
  fread(buf,1,4,fp);    // biXPelsPerMeter
  fread(buf,1,4,fp);    // biYPelsPerMeter
  fread(buf,1,4,fp);    // biClrUsed
  fread(buf,1,4,fp);    // biClrImportant

  // DECODE IMAGE
  uint8_t origin = (biHeight>0 ? 0 : 1);    // 0=bottom-up, 1=up-bottom
  // there are cases where BMP sizes are NOT the same with cursor; we use the cursor ones
  biWidth = width;
  biHeight = height;

  COLOR* pixels = new COLOR[biWidth * biHeight];
  for(int32_t y=0;y<biHeight;y++) {
     for(int32_t x=0;x<biWidth;x++) {
        uint32_t offset = ((origin==1?y:biHeight-1-y)*biWidth)+x;
        // read pixels by number of bits
        switch(biBitCount) {
           // 24-bit
           case 24:
              fread(buf,1,3,fp); 
              pixels[offset] = COLOR(buf[0],buf[1],buf[2]);
           break;
           // 32-bit
           case 32:
              fread(buf,1,4,fp);
              pixels[offset] = COLOR(buf[0],buf[1],buf[2]);
              pixels[offset].a = buf[3];
           break;
        }
     }
  }

  // read mask
  // mask is 1-bit-per-pixel for describing the cursor bitmap's opaque and transparent pixels.
  // so for 1 pixel we need 1 bit, for etc. 32 pixels width, we need 32*1 bits (or 4 bytes per line)
  // so for etc. 32 pixels height we need 4*32 = 128 bytes or [mask bytes per line * height]
  uint16_t mask_bytes_per_line = biWidth / 8;
  uint16_t mask_bytes = mask_bytes_per_line * biHeight;
  char* mask = new char[mask_bytes];

  fread(mask,1,mask_bytes,fp);
  fclose(fp);

  // reverse every [mask_bytes_per_line] bytes; (etc. for 4 bytes per line do:  0,1,2,3 => 3,2,1,0) -> you really need to ask Microsoft for this 8)
  char rmask[4];
  for(uint16_t x=0;x<mask_bytes;x+=mask_bytes_per_line) {
     for(uint16_t r=0;r<mask_bytes_per_line;r++) {
        rmask[r] = mask[x+mask_bytes_per_line-1-r];
     }
     // copy the reversed line
     for(uint16_t r=0;r<mask_bytes_per_line;r++) {
        mask[x+r] = rmask[r];
     }
  }

  // now extract all bits from mask bytes into new array (equal to width*height)
  vector<uint8_t> bits;
  for(uint16_t x=0;x<mask_bytes;x++) {
     for(uint8_t b=0;b<8;b++) {
        bits.push_back( get_bit(mask[x],b) );
     }
  }
  delete[] mask;
  // reverse vector (?)
  reverse(bits.begin(),bits.end());

  // now the bits contains =1 (transparent) and =0 (opaque) which we use on cursor directly
  XcursorImage* cimg = XcursorImageCreate(biWidth,biHeight);
  cimg->xhot = hotspot_x;
  cimg->yhot = hotspot_y;
  // create the image
  for(int32_t y=0;y<biHeight;y++) {
     for(int32_t x=0;x<biWidth;x++) {
        uint32_t offset = (y*biWidth)+x;
        COLOR pix = pixels[offset];
        cimg->pixels[offset] = ((bits[offset]==1?0:pix.a)<<24) + (pix.r<<16) + (pix.g<<8) + (pix.b);
     }
  }
  // create cursor from image and release the image
  Cursor cursor = XcursorImageLoadCursor(display,cimg);
  XcursorImageDestroy(cimg);

  ...
  // set the cursor
  XDefineCursor(display,yourwindow,cursor);
  XFlush(display);

  ...
  // free cursor
  if (cursor!=None) {
     XFreeCursor(display,cursor);
  }
```

The above code takes a Windows `.cur` cursor file and creates an `Xcursor` for use in X11 window system. Of course, there are lots of limitations to my `.cur` format handling but one can easily add his own improvements to the above code (like say supporting `8-bit` cursors). The above code not only take care of alpha-transparency but also *32-bit alpha-blended cursors*